# How to store type T

Tags: c#

What is the equivalent of storing `T` in a list/dictionary (e.g. `Dictionary<string, T>`) if it can be anything and there are no constraints?

I have a method in the form of `Method<T>(string someString)`. In this method, I need to save both the string and `T` for later use. Another method (from another API) will use the string and T. This will happen at a later time in a Task.Run (I think this is irrelevant here).

No `<T>` in this class definition because the class itself doesn't store anything related to `T`.

EDIT: This is the flow:

Somewhere in my code:

`public void MyMethod<T>(string someString) { ... }`

Later on, if some condition met, somewhere else in my code (not necessarily in the class of MyMethod)

`public void SomeMethodFromAnotherAPI<T>(string someString)`

Comment: I didn't know that SE uses <T> for something (metadata?). It appears to have edited the <T> from Method(string someString), which changed the meaning.

Comment: Add it as code using Backticks - see my edit :)

Comment: When you say "for later use", do you mean in a static variable? Also, what should happen if you first call the method with `<int>` and then later with `<string>`, should those two data structures be shared, or separate? Can you please provide an example of how you see the API syntax, ie. the methods you would like to use, and what they should do?

Comment: The notion that a Dictionary or some kind of storage is a solution to your problem made you incapable of describing what actually is the problem.

Comment: The equivalent of storing `T` in a Dictionary is exactly as you suggest: `Dictionary<string, T>`. I can't see the question here. Maybe add some code samples to clarify it?

Comment: How this is unclear (with a marked answer on top of that) is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void TheirMethod<T>(string text) { }

void MyMethod<T>(string text)
{
    Action action = () => TheirMethod<T>(text);
    // you can now return the action,
    // construct a thread with it
    // add it to a List...
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(action));
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

public void Method<T>(string text)
{
    dict.Add(text, typeof(T));
}

public void Usage()
{
    Method<string>("string");
    Method<IList>("list");
    Method<Action>("action");
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you determine what T is in `Usage()`? I need to propagate T all the way to a method in another API. Does this mean that I have to build a switch?

Comment: @RecursiveCall At this point I don't understand at all. Could you perhaps expand your question with a concrete pseudo-code example of what your trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into Generics in C#. This is how C# approaches templating.

[Introduction to Generics.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx)

You may also be trying to simply store the type. At which point you'll want to use the [Type class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)'s [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2wzt390.aspx) method or the [TypeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword to get the type.

Comment: True, this will also work. I'll make a note of it. Thank you.